# How to deal with geopy's query limit?

Tags: python-3.x, geocoding

I am doing a project, in which I need to convert coordinates to street name. We use geopy package but we find that the query limit is really a problem. I have 70K lines of coordinates and I hope to finish converting in 3 days. How can I do this in 3 days? or is there other python package that can do same job without limit?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Geopy just relies on  web API to do the conversion. And, All web API have limits on the amount of queries you can do, particularly if they are free.

You can either look for an API which has higher query limits (probably in exchange for a fee), or, for instance, install Open Street maps [Nominatim](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Nominatim/Installation) on you own server and do as many queries as you like (the process is rather lengthy though).

Comment: I just found that what I used is py geocoder from google at first. But geopy is ok for my mission. When I need more powerful api , I will take your way. Thanks for you advice.

Comment: in case the redirect from the Nominatum link above expires, here's the new link:
https://nominatim.org/release-docs/latest/admin/Installation/